# R, plyr, with a complex function

Tags: r, plyr

I have the following dataset (CEU):

```
group  x      y
1     -23     100
1     -0.90   69.62
1     -0.90   72.03
2     -23     100
2      0.69   48.01
2      0.69   45.63
```

For each value of group, I want to apply functions noted below to each subset of x and y values. I would then like to combine all of the results and write them in a table to export.

I am unsure how exactly to apply the plyr function to do this...if that is indeed the right course of action.

```
x<-c(-23.0000,-0.9031,-0.9031)
y<-c(100,85.72,86.65)

par<-c(16.88,100.28,-.75,4.129)

dcrit<-function(d) { 
    sumsq<-0
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
      sumsq<-sumsq+ (y[i]-(par[1]+(par[2]-par[1])/(1+10^((x[i]-par[3])*d))))^2      
    }
    sumsq
}

S<-function(par) { 
    a<-par[1]
    b<-par[2]
    c<-par[3]
    d<-par[4]
    sumsq<-0
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
      sumsq<-sumsq+ (y[i]-(a+(b-a)/(1+10^((x[i]-c)*d))))^2      
    }
    sumsq
}
optim(par,S)

CEU <- read.csv(file="C:/files/CEU.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
CEU

data <- ddply(CEU,.(group),function(xy) 
{
par[1]<-min(y)
par[2]<-100
par[3]<-x[[which.min(abs(y-50))]]
par[4]<-optimize(dcrit,interval=c(-100,100))$minimum

o<-optim(par,S)
par<-o$par

a<-par[1];
b<-par[2];
c<-par[3];
d<-par[4];

k<-(b-a)/(20-a)-1
if (k>0) ec20<-c+1/d*log10(k) else ec20<-NA
ec20

z<-(b-a)/(50-a)-1
 if (z>0) ec50<-c+1/d*log10(z) else ec50<-NA
ec50

j<-(b-a)/(80-a)-1
if (j>0) ec80<-c+1/d*log10(j) else ec80<-NA
ec80

data.frame(ec20, ec50, ec80)

})

data
```

The code runs without errors but only on the original x and y values set by:

```
 x<-c(-23.0000,-0.9031,-0.9031)
 y<-c(100,85.72,86.65)
```

The x and y values in dataset CEU are not used by ddply. They do not replace the original x and y in an iterative fashion as they do with the group values.  data has the appropriate number of groups and the ec20/ec50/ec80 values are accurate but only for the original x and y.

```
> data
   group       ec20       ec50       ec80
1      1 -0.3652977 -0.6843279 -0.8530892
2      2 -0.3652977 -0.6843279 -0.8530892
3      3 -0.3652977 -0.6843279 -0.8530892
4      4 -0.3652977 -0.6843279 -0.8530892
5      5 -0.3652977 -0.6843279 -0.8530892
```

Comment: Optimize takes a first argument of "f" (a function) and a second argument of "interval" (a range). But you seem to be sending it an undefined function, `dcrit`, and then doing something with the result, but <who-knows-what?> since "S" only appears once in your code.

Comment: Edited the original post with the complete code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have it right, you just need to produce the output.

I'm guessing this is where your outputs are?

```
k<-(b-a)/(20-a)-1
if (k>0) ec20<-c+1/d*log10(k) else ec20<-NA
ec20

z<-(b-a)/(50-a)-1
 if (z>0) ec50<-c+1/d*log10(z) else ec50<-NA
ec50

j<-(b-a)/(80-a)-1
if (j>0) ec80<-c+1/d*log10(j) else ec80<-NA
ec80
```

Put them into a `data.frame` at the end of the function:

```
    ...
    data.frame(ec20, ec50, ec80)
}
```

Now you'll get a `data.frame` with all of them, with three columns for `ec20`, `ec50` and `ec80`

---

To your problem with optim: I think the problem lies in

```
par[3]<-x[which.min(abs(y-50))]
```

Single `[` in R is not regular subscript -- it gets a slice -- in this case of the `data.frame` columns. That line is turning `par` from a numeric vector into a `list`. Add more brackets:

```
par[3]<-x[[which.min(abs(y-50))]]
```

Comment: If this is correct, you are truly a better mind reader than me! ;)

Comment: He's being brave. Ignoring the inconsequential details like defining functions and testing. Cutting to the chase. Let's see... if I give his answer a plus and your comment a plus and a -1 to the (incomplete) questioner... how much am I out?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I realize it was unclear as to what I was trying to do with the optim function initially. My concern isn't whether I am using the optim/dcrit functions properly, I know those work. I would just like to do it an iterative fashion using ddply. Alas, I am getting the following error Error in optim(par, S) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Owen, adding the brackets, creates the following warnings:In par[3] <- x[[which.min(abs(y - 50))]] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @Sash OK hm. What are you trying to do with that line? `x` is a  chunk of `data.frame` and you are selecting one column -- is this what you want to do? Or are you trying to select one row?

Comment: @Owen thanks for your help and patience! I have changed the code and added comments to reflect where I am at now. Thanks!

Comment: @Sash If you want to get the actual columns of your data from `ddply` you should do something like `ddply(CEU, .(group), function(df) with(df, { ... body of code ... }). Then you'll be able to refer to the columns as `x` and `y`.